# How to tell if one generator is a subsequence or a prefix of another generator?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, try-except

I have two generators, `A` and `B`, of unknown length.

I want to know if `B` is a subsequence (contiguous) of `A`, so I do the following:

```
def subseq(A, B):
    b0 = next(B)
    for a in A:
       if a == b0:
           break
    else: # no-break
        # b0 not found in A so B is definitely not a subseq of A
        return False
     # is the remaining of B a prefix of the remaining of B
    return prefix(A, B)

def prefix(A, B):
    return all(a == b for a, b in zip(A, B))
```

However, `prefix(A, B)` is not exactly correct, as if what remains of `A` is shorter than what remains of `B`, then I might get a false positive:

E.g. with `A = 'abc'` and `B = 'abcd'` (imagine they are generators), then `return all(a == b for a, b in zip(A, B))` would return `True`.

But if I use `zip_longest` instead, then I have the complimentary problem -- I would get false negatives:

E.g. with `A = 'abcd'` and `B = 'abc'`, then `return all(a == b for a, b in zip_longest(A, B))` would return `False`.

---

What's a sensible way to do this? Specifically, I want to zip to the length of the second argument. I basically want something like `zip_(A, B, ziplengthselect=1)`

where `ziplengthselect=i` tells the function that it should zip to the length of the `i`th argument.

Then the expression `all(a == b for a, b in zip_(A, B, fillvalue=sentinel, ziplengthselect=1))` where `sentinel` is something not found in `B`, would have the following behavior. If the expression

- reaches end of `B`, then it would evaluate to `True`
- reaches end of `A`, then it would use the fillvalue, check `sentinel == b`, fail the check since `sentinel` was chosen to be something not found in `B`, and return False
- fails an `a == b` check, then it would evaluate to `False`

---

I can think of solutions with `try`, `except` blocks, but was wondering if there's a better way.

```
# Whether generator B is a prefix of generator A. 
def prefix(A, B):
    for b in B:
        try:
            a = next(A)
            if a != b:
                return False
        except StopIteration:
            # reached end of A
            return False
    return True
```

OR

```
# Whether generator B is a prefix of generator A. 
def prefix(A, B):
    prefix = all(a == b for a, b in zip(A, B))
    if not prefix:
        return False
    try:
        next(B)
        # end of B was reached
        return True
    except StopIteration:
        # end of B was not reached
        return False
```

---

The above code works when `A` has no duplicates. However if `A` has duplicates, then we have to `tee` the generators as follows:

```
from itertools import tee

def subseq(A, B):
    try:
        b0 = next(B)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    
    while True:
        try:
            a = next(A)
            if a == b0:
                A, Acop = tee(A)
                B, Bcop = tee(B)
                if prefix(Acop, Bcop):
                    return True
                del Acop, Bcop
        except StopIteration:
            return False
            
def prefix(A, B):
    for b in B:
        try:
            a = next(A)
            if a != b:
                return False
        except StopIteration:
            # reached end of A
            return False
    return True


# Some tests
A = (i for i in range(10))
B = (i for i in range(5,8))
print(subseq(A, B)) # True

A = (i for i in range(10))
B = (i for i in range(5,11))
print(subseq(A, B)) # False

A = (i for i in [1,2,3]*10 + [1,2,3,4])
B = (i for i in [1,2,3])
print(subseq(A, B)) # True

A = (i for i in [1,1,2,1,1,2]*8 + [3])
B = (i for i in [1,1,2,3])
print(subseq(A, B)) # True
```

---

Here's how I solved the analogous subsequence problem for lists. Lists are easier because you can know their length:

```
    def isSublist(lst, sublst):
        N, M = len(lst), len(sublst)
        starts = (i for i in range(N - M + 1) if lst[i] == sublst[0])

        for i in starts:
            # i <= N - M so N - i >= M
            j = 0
            while j < M and lst[i] == sublst[j]:
                i += 1
                j += 1
            if j == M:
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: Is subsequence really a part of the question or just a distraction?

Comment: Fair question. I found a solution of the subsequence problem that simplified to the prefix problem. Ultimately, I'm interested in the subsequence problem, so I included it as well, in case someone happens to think of a solution that bypasses the prefix issue entirely.

Comment: Your solution for lists isn't correct either since you only look for the first occurrence of the first item of the second list in the first list. The subsequence may very well occur later even if the first attempt to match the rest of the second list against the first list fails, e.g. checking `'bcd'` against `'abcbcd'` would fail with your approach.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks. You're correct. Fixed the sublist code, but I think the generator code has the same issue.

Comment: Added version of generator code that handles generators with duplicates.

Comment: This is impossible for arbitrary generators without keeping a memory of `B`’s past output. Since `B` has to be finite anyway, I would recommend materializing `B` to a sequence and picking a string search algorithm.

Comment: @Ry- Now that you mention it... I don't think `B` has to be finite. Why do you think so?

Comment: @KellyBundy: It has to be finite in order to return `True`, anyway, and at least one of them has to be finite in order for it to terminate at all.

Answer (score 2):

I might use deques (although this assumes `B` is finite):

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

def subseq(A, B):
    B = deque(B)
    if not B:
        return True
    n = len(B)
    Asub = deque(islice(A, n-1), n)
    for a in A:
        Asub.append(a)
        if Asub == B:
            return True
    return False
```

Might take more or less time/memory than yours. Depends on the input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLLTsQgFN3zFTeZxcBYzdTRpDGZRbvwB3RnuqDtrZK0wABd@PUVSq2j1kRlQXI4nAcP/epelDxk2oxja1QPteo6rJ1Q0oLotTIOGjwNSCZWODROqW7hhO1EjYQ02IIdKosnmidQsDsCfhRwjGpasGlBtCCVgyLSYRh0g5HwaHxEwNJLOpTvgtybLiYxLATIy5T5Oe5plQEOQkL@YRt0V1xrlA3lbFn2@dHxeN5hrceM73ln/fE28KB6BIfWWZL7QlRMsSLEGi6fkaZ7xkixSt0mmee0EdLR80tisImB/7FM0x8959JfTZ/S5Do5lLt0DxczSG7K7wnzvr819qIgm@Zyl4WEw7r3b9w/ceHT0S2v6qputv7ZI57AIhnHNw)

A note about yours: For an input like `A = iter('a'+'b'*10**7)`, `B = iter('ac')` you waste a lot of memory (90 MB on 64-bit Python), since your `Acop` from the very beginning causes the underlying `tee` storage to never let go of anything. You'd better do `del Acop, Bcop` after an unsuccessful `prefix` check.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great solution. I appreciate how when you append to `Asub`, it automatically pops the leftmost element to maintain the size of `n`.

This solution also gave me an idea for how to mitigate a big `B`. We could break `B` and `A` into chunks. At first, we'd just evaluate one chunk `Bchunks = [queue(islice(B, chunksize)]` and `Achunks = [queue(islice(A, chunksize-1), chunksize))`. As soon as we have a match on the first chunks, then we'd evalute the next chunks, and so on until there's a full match or we exhaust `A`.

Comment: @joseville I considered using chunks as well, but didn't want to complicate it. The only more complicated solution I might try is a lazy KMP (not building the table in advance but just as needed).

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible to build [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)’s partial match table lazily.

```
from itertools import islice


def has_substring(sup, sub):
    sub = LazySequence(sub)

    if not sub:
        return True

    t = kmp_table(sub)
    k = 0

    for x in sup:
        while x != sub[k]:
            k = t[k]
            if k == -1:
                break

        if k == -1:
            k = 0
            continue

        k += 1

        try:
            sub[k]
        except IndexError:
            return True

    return False


class LazySequence:

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.consumed = []
        self.iterator = None if iterator is None else iter(iterator)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index >= len(self.consumed):
            self.consumed.extend(islice(self.iterator, index - len(self.consumed) + 1))

        return self.consumed[index]

    def __iter__(self):
        consumed = self.consumed
        yield from consumed

        for x in self.iterator:
            consumed.append(x)
            yield x

    def __bool__(self):
        for _ in self:
            return True
        return False


def lazy_sequence(g):
    def wrap_generator(*args, **kwargs):
        ls = LazySequence(None)
        ls.iterator = g(ls.consumed, *args, **kwargs)
        return ls

    return wrap_generator


@lazy_sequence
def kmp_table(t, w):
    yield -1
    cnd = 0

    for x in islice(w, 1, None):
        if x == w[cnd]:
            yield t[cnd]
        else:
            yield cnd
            while cnd != -1 and x != w[cnd]:
                cnd = t[cnd]
        cnd += 1
```

This search is fast (asymptotically optimal time of O(|sub| + |sup|)) and doesn’t use unnecessary time/space when one generator is much longer than the other – including being able to return `True` when `sup` is infinite and being able to return `False` when `sub` is infinite.